# Is this way of messing with physics possible?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, magic, physics

So, I am trying to build a world in which stuff like magic is possible, but the "magic" here is physically explicable by science, although the inhabitants in the world may be a long way from that explanation.

**The explicit effect of the magic:**
people, or otherwise magical machinery can do things like glowing, heating, cooling, telekinesis (that conserve momentum), or catalyzing unlikely reactions. All of which macroscopically preserve the laws of physics.

**proposed canonical explanation:**
I want to know if this explanation, which includes a few assumptions, is plausible:

> It is assumed that subatomic particles is much more complex than is apparent to observations up to date, and that persistent modification to subatomic particles is possible.
>
> At some point, some alien intelligence modified a vast number of particles, making them function like subatomic robots and inducing behaviors that is unlike any naturally occurring particles.
>
> To take an example that may be impossible itself but serves to demonstrate the general point: A modified particle can behave like a neutrino until it enters a strong electromagnetic field, at which point it begin to behave like a positronium.
>
> These modified subatomic particles interacts with ordinary matter and each other to produce the effect of apparent magic.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're hoping to accomplish by asking this question. You're inventing entirely new realms of physics, and you're wondering about whether or not the result is plausible? It directly contradicts our current understanding of the universe, so what are your criteria for plausibility? And if your inhabitants don't even know the details of the system, why is it important to construct the science behind the magic in such detail? It seems to me that you stand to lose nothing just by setting the rules of your universe as you see fit and not worrying about this reality.

Comment: You need a source of **power**.

Comment: Your particles sound a lot like something from the book "The Three Body Problem", where some atomic particles are turned into a kind of super computer to mess with humanity.

Comment: I believe you're asking a question beyond the abilities of even a preeminent expert in the field of sub-atomic physics to answer in the affirmative. I.e. it contradicts and/or proposes things outside our understanding of physics. You've also said it's beyond the understanding of your conworld's inhabitants, so what is there to be gained by this answer?

Comment: This isn't as unthinkable as appears to be the case. So if particles have been turned into 'subatomic robots' that can change their properties depending on certain circumstances. The SARs make magic happen. Lots of problems. Who & how is this controlled? A particle that acts like a neutrino until it hits an EM field then it's positronium. Even if this was the case, it's hard to see how this could be the basis for working magic. The people in this world need to know how to work magic even if they don't understand its actual scientific basis. Waves powerful magnet and -- what? (to be continued).

Comment: You might find you need to work out how every particle has been modified and what its effect would be before you have a sensible schema for the magic. Perhaps you as the author may want to know how your world works. The characters don't need it nor will most of your readers. Why not simply devise magic & make sure it doesn't violate the laws of nature. Pixie dust might be SARs. Sprinkle & it's magic! Science isn't needed explain everything especially in a fantasy world. Just keep it logically consistent in your world, that's enough for most fantasy writers.

Comment: Essentially you are asking: "Can I break the laws of physics while not breaking the laws of physics?". Short answer: no. Long answer: yes, but only if you invent new physics that has not yet been in play before, which is to say: magic. The problem with your suggestion is that the reader will probably think it convoluted or boring in that it tries to explain the — presently — entirely unexplainable. @JDługosz suggestion works better: that your magic allows you to create energy, or draw energy from a hidden source. If you allow there to be a hidden dimension with lots of energy this is credible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know it now? This is ridiculous.

Matter is made of atoms. Atoms are made of subatomic particles, and these, in turn, are either leptons, or are made of quarks.

There is only so much you can do about them.

> A modified particle can behave like a neutrino until it enters a strong electromagnetic field, at which point it begin to behave like a positronium.

This is not possible within the physics we know. Positronium is an exotic atom, made of two leptons. Neutrino is one lepton. Another mass, another energy, and neutrinos does not interact with electric field much. Or rather - at all.

Of course standard model isn't perfect, but you would have to "invent" a few new "levels" of physics, deeper than standard model, to make it kinda work. Still, it wouldn't go well with the physics as we know it.

---

I'd suggest you not to bother. It's a waste of time for readers who don't know or don't care about physics, and even worse for ones that do,